# What exactly is the problem with using electronic codebooks as a block cipher mode

Tags: ecb

I was wondering why it is a problem with using ECB as a block cipher mode

Comment: Also. it can cause a [frequency attack on encrypted databases](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/74786/18298).

Answer (score 2):

ECB leaks if blocks are identical or not. This may seem like a small matter, but depending on the data format it can be quite damaging. This is commonly exemplified via the "ECB penguin". One can easily see that encryption of the plaintext (image in this case) does not provide much privacy.

[image]